# How do you Precompile all Javascript Files except One?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

To avoid "assets not compiled" errors in production on my Rails 3.2 site, I added the following line to production.rb:

```
  config.assets.precompile += ['*.js']
```

This precompiles all the .js files in vendor so if they're ready when called from inside a page. Unfortunately one of the .js files cannot precompile without errors, so I want to skip it. How can I precompile all .js files except one file, `bad-file.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You might do it like this in application.rb

```
    config.assets.precompile << Proc.new do |path|
      if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/ &&  path!~ /bad-file\.js\z/
        full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
        app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
        if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
          puts "including asset: " + full_path
          true
        else
          puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
          false
        end
      else
        false
      end
    end
```

You might also do it in a simple way, I tested it a little, not the same name.

```
config.assets.precompile = [/^((?!bad-file\.js).)*$/]
```

That mean the file path should not contain the substring "bad-file.js". You can improve the regexp more accurately, add the directory information or something.

Answer (score 0):

In your production.rb file try adding this.

config.assets.precompile += %w( bad-file.js )